# Window version of Docker not able to mount local directory to ubuntu image on container?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, docker, dockerfile

I have a docker image setup to run NGINX on a Ubuntu image which is a container. During the runtime, I would like to mount the directory as follows when bringing up the Docker image

```
docker run -v C:/Docker/webroot:/var/www/html -p 8080:80 --name default nginx_image
```

However, the above command give me the following error when I look at the log

[20:18:03.853][ApiProxy ][Info ] Rewrote mount C:/Docker/webroot:/var/www/html (volumeDriver=) to /C/Docker/webroot:/var/www/html

[20:18:03.870][ApiProxy ][Info ] Failed to Walk to [snapshots c99a6d868eda009bf52542988015ef5676b2015b ro com.docker.driver.amd64-linux proxy http] 9p: No such file or directory

I have tried different ways of writting the window path, but it does not help. I also checked by login on to the Docker image /var/www/html directory is created there.

Additional info:

I have my Dockerfile as follows when I build the image:

```
#Download base image ubuntu 16.04
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Update Software repository
RUN apt-get update

# Install nginx, php-fpm and supervisord from ubuntu repository
RUN apt-get install -y nginx php7.0-fpm supervisor && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#Define the ENV variable
ENV nginx_vhost /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
ENV php_conf /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
ENV nginx_conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ENV supervisor_conf /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf

# Enable php-fpm on nginx virtualhost configuration
COPY default ${nginx_vhost}
RUN sed -i -e 's/;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1/cgi.fix_pathinfo=0/g' ${php_conf} && \
    echo "\ndaemon off;" >> ${nginx_conf}

#Copy supervisor configuration
COPY supervisord.conf ${supervisor_conf}

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html && \
    mkdir -p /run/php && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /run/php

# Volume configuration
VOLUME ["/etc/nginx/sites-enabled", "/etc/nginx/certs", "/etc/nginx/conf.d", "/var/log/nginx", "/var/www/html"]

# Configure Services and Port
COPY start.sh /start.sh
CMD ["./start.sh"]

EXPOSE 80 443
```

Comment: Does it work without the volume mount? Do the docker settings include the C drive in the list of shared drives?

Comment: Hmm looks like some other problem. It didn't work even if I removed -v C:/Docker/webroot:/var/www/html and YES C drive is shared.

Comment: I have updated my question with my docker build file. Maybe there is more clue there. @BMitch

Comment: Please check if the sed command is correct?

Comment: Found the issue it was due to the window carriage return which I wrote the script #!/bin/sh. Thanks for the help! @Rao